# How can I perform a right tailed hypothesis test without t.test?

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

From what I understand, this method of doing a t-test will do a regular, left-tailed t-test.

```
t <- (NFL.Broncos.LowSpread$PerformanceScoreOff - mean(NFL.Broncos$PerformanceScoreOff)) / (sd(NFL.Broncos$PerformanceScoreOff)/sqrt(nrow(NFL.Broncos)))

p_value <- pt(t, nrow(NFL.Broncos)-1)
```

I understand that the 't.test' function exists to use:

```
t.test(x,y, mu, alt="greater")
```

but I'm updating some old code so I want to keep it in raw form.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This should do it `p_value <- pt(t, nrow(NFL.Broncos)-1, lower.tail=FALSE)` or `p_value <- 1 - pt(t, nrow(NFL.Broncos)-1)`.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you :)